# jQuery CDN secure/insecure loading issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ssl

I'm experiencing an issue with the jQuery CDN.

Given the following script imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am having the following issues with the CDN paths:

1. Using `http://...` when accessing my site over SSL I get

> [blocked] The page at https://www.example.com/ ran insecure content from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js.
>
> Using `https://...` seems a bit dodgy if not accessing site over SSL
>
> Using `//...` causes both the imports to fail on GET.
>
> What is the correct way of importing jQuery from CDN with a site that can be accessed both securely and not.

Comment: how are you saying the third option is failing

Comment: did you try `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`, it seems fine http://plnkr.co/edit/6uFktr3TaBMWbEUdsvmZ?p=preview

Comment: it will fail if you are loading the page from local file system instead of a web server

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ahh - would that happen even on a local IIS?

Comment: no... if it is loading from a local web server with `http://` or `https://` address it will work fine

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` will work on production server..

Comment: @ArunPJohny If you put your local file system comment as an answer I will accept. I believe that is what is occurring here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just omit the protocol, then the script will be loaded using the same protocol as the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But if the resource is loaded form the file system(with file:// protocol) then this will not work